# How to save last searched when using search on input?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, search

I am trying to write an algorithm that saves the recently searched keywords. The issue is that the user is not triggering the search but instead the search is being triggered every time something is typed. Currently, I am trying to save the last searched keyword and checking if the next one starts with the last one in order to discard the last one.

```
async _persistSearch(term) {
        const serachLog = await this._getLastSearchedFile()
        console.log("[SEARCH]", serachLog);
        if (Object.keys(serachLog) == 0) {
            serachLog.searches = [term];
            serachLog.lastUpdated = Date.now()
        } else if (term.startsWith(this.lastSearhed)) {
            const toPersist = serachLog.searches.filter((value) => value != this.lastSearhed).push(term);
            serachLog.searches = toPersist;
        } else {
            serachLog.searches.push(term);
        }
        this.lastSearhed = term;
        await writeJSONFile(this.searchesFile, serachLog);
    }
```

For example for an input [so, som, some, somet, someth,somethi, somethin, something, somethin] to be [something]

Comment: this just sounds like you need to debounce your search input? what's the value in knowing all of the previous search terms?

Comment: thanks, debouncing worked fine

Comment: Usually does, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You should use Trie(Prefix Tree) to save searched keywords. Say you are only dealing with lower-case English letters, then each node can have up to 26 children nodes. For each new search keyword, call the startsWith method to check if this new keyword is any prefix of the previous keywords.

Read about this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie if you need more explanations about why a Trie should be used in your case.

A java implementation of this data structure is as following.

```
class Trie {
    class TrieNode{
        private char c;
        private Map<Character, TrieNode> map;
        private boolean isLeaf;   

        TrieNode() {
            this.map = new HashMap<>();
        }
        TrieNode(char c) {
            this.c = c;
            this.map = new HashMap<>();
        }
    }
    private TrieNode root;
    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    public Trie() {
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    /** Inserts a word into the trie. */
    public void insert(String word) {
        TrieNode currNode = root;
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char currChar = word.charAt(i);
            if(!currNode.map.containsKey(currChar)) {
                TrieNode newNode = new TrieNode(currChar);    
                currNode.map.put(currChar, newNode);
                currNode = newNode;
            }
            else {
                currNode = currNode.map.get(currChar);
            }
            if(i == word.length() - 1) {
                currNode.isLeaf = true;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Returns if the word is in the trie. */
    public boolean search(String word) {
        TrieNode currNode = root;
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if(!currNode.map.containsKey(word.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
            currNode = currNode.map.get(word.charAt(i));
            if( i == word.length() - 1 && !currNode.isLeaf) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /** Returns if there is any word in the trie that starts with the given prefix. */
    public boolean startsWith(String prefix) {
        TrieNode currNode = root;
        for(int i = 0; i < prefix.length(); i++) {
            if(!currNode.map.containsKey(prefix.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
            currNode = currNode.map.get(prefix.charAt(i));
        }
        return true;        
    }
}
```